# angular 2 how to bind two components behavior

Tags: angular, typescript

I've two equal components

```
<component><component>

<component><component>
```

I need that if one of them change the another one change too, e.g if I've a function that when I click the element write 'hello' if i do it in one of them it be reflected in both components, how can i achieve that?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<component #c1 (click)="c2.title = 'hello'"><component>

<component #c2 (click)="c1.title = 'hello'"><component>
```

For other ways see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html